# How do I add together fields from a manytomanyfield in django?

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions, django-orm, manytomanyfield

I am creating a quote-generator in Django. I want to calculate the total of all items, insert it into a field, and save it.

The models are as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('product_name',)


class Quote(models.Model):
    quotee_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=40)
    quotee_email = models.EmailField("Email")
    quotee_phone = models.IntegerField("Phone", max_length=10)
    quotee_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name="Products")
    quotee_total = models.IntegerField("Estimate", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quotee_email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('quotee_email',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('quote-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, })
```

I am not using this through the Admin, so here is the forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple


from InternalDusettenet.apps.quotes.models import Quote


class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('quotee_name', 'quotee_email', 'quotee_phone',
                  'quotee_products')
        widgets = {
            'quotee_products': CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 10}),
        }
```

And here is the views.py file. I have it set to just save a '1' into the form so that it actually saves. What I want is to replace the '1' with a function that returns the value of 'Product.product_price' for every one selected in 'Quote.quotee_products'. When I create a quote, I select the products, and it gives me the sum of all selected 'product_price' fields related to the selected products:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import Http404, get_object_or_404

from InternalDusettenet.apps.quotes.models import Quote
from InternalDusettenet.apps.quotes.forms import QuoteForm


class QuoteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = "quotes/quote_create_edit.html"
    fields = ['quotee_name', 'quotee_email', 'quotee_phone',
              'quotee_products']
    form_class = QuoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.quotee_total = 1
        return super(QuoteCreate, self).form_valid(form)


class QuoteList(ListView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = "quotes/quote_list.html"


class QuoteDetail(DetailView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = "quotes/quote_detail.html"


class QuoteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = "quotes/quote_create_edit.html"
    fields = ['quotee_name', 'quotee_email', 'quotee_phone',
              'quotee_products', 'quotee_total']
    form_class = QuoteForm


class QuoteDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Quote
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = "quotes/quote_delete.html"
```

I have read the Django docs MANY times but I have no clue how to do this one simple thing.

I am using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

No reason to save it in the database, just make it a method or property of the `Quote` object:

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    ...
    def quotee_total(self):
        return self.quotee_products.aggregate(total=models.Sum('product_price'))['total']
```

If need be, you can cache the value and fill the cache on the initial query:

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    ...
    def quotee_total(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_quotee_total'):
            self._quotee_total = self.quotee_products.aggregate(total=models.Sum('product_price'))['total']
        return self._quotee_total

quotes = Quote.objects.annotate(_quotee_total=models.Sum('quotee_products__product_price'))
```

You can of course save that value in the database, but there's little reason. If you're worried about performance, that is better handled with caching than with saving the value to the database.

Comment: Using aggregate() is probably a bit more efficient than the way I suggested. 

NB: The Sum() function should not be confused with the builtin python function sum(). Use `from django.db.models import Sum`

Comment: @HåkenLid Meant to write `models.Sum` as `models` is already imported :P That should be clear enough, but thanks for the note.

Comment: Wow. So many comments. Thank you all so much. 

For this one, the only reason I need to see the quotes is in a view. It does not need to be stored in the db. I just need the total ready when I query that particular quote.

Sorry for being a rookie, but if  made it a method like in your first example, how would I get be able to call that via a view/template?

Again. sorry for not getting it. lol. I am usually VERY good at figuring things out, but this one is just confusing me. Thanks.

Comment: If `quote`  is your `Quote` instance, use `quote.quotee_total()` in the view and `{{ quote.quotee_total }}` in the template. Functions and methods with no arguments besides `self` are automatically called in templates.

Comment: GOOD STUFF! Thanks! I was driving my head through the wall, and I knew it was something simple. I will get back if I have any more problems, but this is pretty concise.

Comment: So, that totally worked. The first solution @knbk suggested worked with NO problem. I simply removed that field from my model, and added that method, and it worked. Also, that just taught me a LOT that I happened to forget about my early Django studies. Now that I see that, you have opened up a great many more options for me. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would not calculate the total in a view. This makes more sense as a method.

```
class Quote(models.Model):

    def calculate_quotee_total(self):
        return sum(product.product_price for product in self.quotee_products.all())

    def __save__(self):
        self.quotee_total = self.calculate_quotee_total()
        super(Quote, self).save()
```

Quote.quotee_total could also be calculated as needed, instead of saving it in the db.

```
class Quote(models.Model):

    @property
    def quotee_total(self):
        return sum(product.product_price for product in self.quotee_products.all())
```